# exit status в bash (диапазон значений)

Tags: linux, bash

Существуют ли ограничения на значение exit status bash скрипта. Где-то вычитал, что он ограничен числом в диапазоне 0-255 (unsigned char похоже) но источник доверия не внушает.

Т.е. могу ли я в в perl скрипте (например) написать что-то вроде:

```
exit 1111111111 unless do_something;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> могу ли я в в perl скрипте (например) написать что-то вроде

конечно, можете. но статус будет не такой, как вы указали:

```
$ ( exit 1111111111 ); echo $?
199
```

он будет равен остатку от деления этого числа на 256:

```
$ echo $((1111111111%256))
199
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо, как-то я не сообразил сам проверить)